# convert a list in a colum of a data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I would like to create a data.frame or tibble with a column from a list, I tried this

```
tlist <- list(A=matrix(runif(100),10), b=runif(10),bb=runif(20))

tibble(c=10,tlist)
```

but the result is

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      c tlist               
  <dbl> <named list>        
1    10 <dbl[,10] [10 × 10]>
2    10 <dbl [10]>          
3    10 <dbl [20]>
```

what I would like is a tibble with one row and two columns `c` and `tlist`

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      c tlist               
  <dbl> <named list>        
1    10 <dbl[,10] [10 × 10] ... >
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Comment: the output is described I cant produce it

Comment: Even if you can't produce it, type it out as a table or even draw us a picture of it. It's unclear from the description—everything becomes a single-row data frame? With how many columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add one more layer of `list()`

```
tlist <-list(list(A=matrix(runif(100),10), b=runif(10),bb=runif(20)))
tibble(c=10,tlist)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
      c tlist           
  <dbl> <list>          
1    10 <named list [3]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the list further.

For `tibble`:

```
# Wrap list inside list
tib <- tibble(c=10, list_col = list(tlist=tlist))

str(tib$list_col)
# list_col is a list with all the rows (now only tlist) in this column

str(tib$list_col$tlist)
str(tib$list_col[[1]])
# original tlist on first row
```

For `data.frame`

```
# List of list does not work for data.frame. Treat 'as is' with I()
df <- data.frame(c=10, list_col=I(list(tlist123=tlist)))
# Mind that this sets the row names to the names of the inner list (tlist123 here)
```

For `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

# Wrapping list inside list is enough
dt <- data.table(c=10, list_col=list(tlist=tlist))
```